# Insert in list at second position c++

Tags: c++

I would like to insert an element inside a list, as second element, creating a new list without modifying original one.

Example: 
list 1 2 3 4 5, cin>> 55, then new list become 1 55 2 3 4 5.

Problem is that both lists are modified. Why is this happening?

```
ptr_list insertAfterFirstElem(ptr_list head){
    ptr_list tmp;
    tmp=new list;
    cout<<"Insert value"<<endl;
    cin>>tmp->val;
    tmp->next=head->next;
    head->next=tmp;
    return (head);

}
```

I wrote a insertAtTop function that works fine:

```
ptr_list insertAtTop(ptr_list head){
    ptr_list tmp;
    tmp=head;
    head=new list;
    cout<<"Insert value"<<endl;
    cin>>head->val;
    head->next=tmp;
    return (head);

}
```

Can you explain what is the difference between these two functions? Why insertAtTop() does not modify the original list?

Comment: Where are you creating a new list? You are creating a new node and are adding it to the original list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both lists share the same cells; that's why you have trouble.

```
head: xxx -> yyy -> zzz -> ttt
       ^
res: --|
```

If `tmp` = uuu, you are inserting it at second position,

```
head: xxx -> uuu-> yyy -> zzz -> ttt
       ^      ^
res: --|      |-- tmp
```

But, as you can see, the original list starting from `head` is also modified.

If you don't want to modify it you need to duplicate the original list before the insertion:

```
head: xxx -> yyy -> zzz -> ttt
copy: xxx -> yyy -> zzz -> ttt
       ^
res: --|
```

then you can insert

```
head: xxx -> yyy -> zzz -> ttt
copy: xxx -> uuu-> yyy -> zzz -> ttt
       ^      ^
res: --|      |-- tmp
```

A possible solution could be:

```
ptr_list copyList(ptr_list head) {
    ptr_list copy = nullptr;
    ptr_list* copy_last = &copy;
    for (ptr_list iter = head; iter != nullptr; iter = iter->next) {
      *copy_last = new list(*iter);
      copy_last->val = iter->val;
      copy_last->next = nullptr;
      copy_last = &copy_last->next;
    };
    return copy;
}

ptr_list insertAfterFirstElem(ptr_list head){
    ptr_list copy = copyList(head);
    ptr_list tmp;
    tmp=new list;
    cout<<"Insert value"<<endl;
    cin>>tmp->val;
    tmp->next=copy->next;
    copy->next=tmp;
    return (copy);
}
```

Now with `insertAtTop(ptr_list head)` you still have problems of sharing but you don't see it immediately. It creates

```
    head: xxx -> yyy -> zzz -> ttt
           ^
res: uuu --|
```

So if after some time, you want to insert another cell in second position from `head` you will also modify your result.

An implementation without any shares of `insertAtTop` is

```
ptr_list insertAtTop(ptr_list head){
    head = copyList(head);
    ptr_list tmp;
    ...
}
```

Also don't forget to free the cells. Freeing with shares is almost impossible if you don't use additional mechanism like [reference-counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613299/simple-reference-counting-smart-pointers)).

Comment: @slash89mf you need to make a copy of the whole list and add your new node to it.

Comment: Just added some code to original question, please check it

Comment: @slash89mf Your insertAtTop function just adds a node to the beginning of the list. The rest of the list is still the old one. If you want to create a new list, you really need to do it yourself.

I think the problem you are having is because the object you're creating is called 'list' but it's really just a node in a list. Just rename it to 'list_node' and it'll be a lot easier for you to understand.